# How do I upload an image on Colab via PIL?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

```
imgs_folder = os.path.join( base_folder, 'My Drive' )
image_filepath = os.path.join( imgs_folder, 'chicken.jpeg' )
img = Image.open(image_filepath) #make image PIL
```

I tried to do the above but there's always this error:

```
   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode)
       2807 
       2808     if filename:
    -> 2809         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
       2810         exclusive_fp = True
       2811 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '##PUT YOUR FOLDER HERE##/My Drive/chicken.jpeg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line, it may help. You also need to mount drive first.

```
imgs_folder = '/content/drive'
```

See the error, it said it cannot find the file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do this in all of my notebooks:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
DRIVE_BASE = '/content/gdrive/My Drive'
```